# Finding the xpath of a class name with \n and spaces

Tags: xpath, scrapy

This may be an easy question, I'm new to this.

I'm trying to get the data within this div

```
<div class="search-results-listings
        " vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="SearchResultsPage">
```

response.xpath("//div[@class='search-results-listings\n']")
and
response.xpath("//div[@class='search-results-listings\n       ']")
are returning empty arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XPath`'s `contains`:

```
response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'search-results-listings')]")
```